# Adding item to ArrayList not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im trying to add text from an input textbox to an ArrayList when a button is click:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim peopleArrayList As New ArrayList

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        peopleArrayList.Add(TextBox1.Text)
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        GridView1.DataSource = peopleArrayList
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

End Class
```

It works but seems to be overwriting any existing items, so it only ever has one item. I would expect that as I add items the GridView would expand with each added item but it only seems to show the last one added.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking it's because it's refreshing the page? Would I need to then save the array to something like a session?

Comment: It's not 2004.  Don't use an `ArrayList` for anything.  `List(Of T)` is where it's at, Daddyo.

Comment: Mate I know, unfortunately this is a university subject and they're always about 10 years behind the trend.

Comment: I hear you.  At least they're not effectively teaching you VB6 with a .NET compiler, which we see quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try a static variable.
such as: (I am not familiar with VB)

> static Dim peopleArrayList As New ArrayList

Comment: The VB equivalent of `static` is `Shared`.